# I can't connect to ms sql instance - internal

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, amazon-web-services, cloud

The Platform and Software versions I am using are as follows :

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU3-GDR) (KB4052987) - 14.0.3015.40 (X64) 
Dec 22 2017 16:13:22 
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation Express Edition (64-bit) on
Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600:) (Hypervisor)
```

I have searched a lot for answers on Google but haven't found any solution yet. I can't connect to `RDS instance having MS SQL instance` via Linux.

It shows following errors If I try to :

```
[ec2-user@ip-~]$ sqlcmd -H mssqldb.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com -P 1433
                        -U userXXXXX -P aXXXXXX
                        -Q 'SELECT TOP 1 [n] FROM [dbbase2].[dbo].[table_people]'

Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server :
               Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server :
               TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server :
               A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
               establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server is not found
               or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL
               Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more
               information see SQL Server Books Online.

[ec2-user@ip- ~]$  Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
                   configured to allow remote connections.
```

Could anyone please tell the issue and resolution ?

Thanks.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT

I tried to run:
sqlcmd -S EC2XXXXXXXX -d dbXXXX -P 1433 -U userXXXXX -P aXXXXX -Q 'SELECT SELECT TOP 1 [n] FROM [Nums]'
or:
sqlcmd -S EC2XXXXXXXX -d dbXXXX -P 1433 -U userXXXXX -P aXXXXX

Is the same error. 

I have got only a connection by SQL Server Management Studio from Windows 7 but there is a still a problem when I would like to connect through Linux.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT
I suspect but I'm not sure that maybe it is a problem with SQL Server Configuration Manager where I should set up  TCP/IP protocols but I don't have access to this tool.

Comment: What I checked in Linux
{ I first run commands:
sudo yum check-update and sudo yum update mssql-toolsthen I run:
sqlcmd -S EC2XXXX-SERVERNAME\INSTANCE,1433
[ec2-user@ip-1 ~]$ sqlcmd -S EC2XXXX-SERVERNAME\INSTANCE,1433
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AF9.

Comment: In Windows this works and port is open every time:
{telnet instance.XX..rds.amazonaws.com 1433}When I am checking telnet in Linux I see after a few seconds:{Trying 1XX.XX.XXX.XXX...Connected to INSTANCE.X.rds.amazonaws.com.Escape character is '^]'.Connection closed by foreign host. }

Comment: What do you mean about the specific version of the SQL Server instance? What is the quickest way to remove 17 ver drivers and install ODBC drivers 16 or 15?

Comment: Ok, right. My version of MS SQL is on the top of this topic. This is :Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU3-GDR) (KB4052987) - 14.0.3015.40 (X64) 
Dec 22 2017 16:13:22 
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation Express Edition (64-bit) on
Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600:) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Btw, I will be trying to solve this issue. Thanks for that.

Comment: Were you able to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error. It was because I used `-H mssqlserver` instead of `-S mysqlserver`

This worked for me

```sh
sqlcmd -U sa -S mssqlserver -P secret
```

In the question the `-P` option is used for *port* and *password*, but it is only supported for the password.

If e port different from `1433` should be used, then pass it with the host name

```sh
sqlcmd -U sa -S mssqlserver,1444 -P secret
```

`sqlcmd` Install instructions can be found in
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15

In case anybody cares about Emacs Org-babel

```
#+HEADER: :results table :engine mssql :dbhost mssqlserver :database master :dbuser sa :dbpassword secret
#+begin_src sql
SELECT name, database_id, create_date
FROM sys.databases;
#+end_src
```

Found in

- https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/e9lrcp/how_to_use_sqlmode_or_org_babel_to_execute_mssql/fakr7nw?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x
- https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/39112/org-babel-using-properties-as-code-block-header-arguments-how-to-make-it-work

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
telnet mssqldb.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com 1433
```

should open connection to the port.

make sure default instance exists (not named instance) otherwise provide the instance name in the command.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was using a different port 1434.
And I had to append it to the servername in the connectionstring using a comma:

```
sqlcmd -S SERVERNAME,1434 -U sa -P 'MySecret'
```